# Error occured when trying to deallocate the memory for array

Tags: pointers, memory, dynamic, heap-memory

I encountered some problem when trying to delete the memory allocated for array when coding in c++ with both compile online and xcode. The code snippet is listed as below. the delete function doesn't work well.... Hope someone can help me out!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int *p;
   p = new int[20];
   for(int i=0;(p+i)<(p+20*sizeof(int));i++)
   {
       p[i]=i;
   }

   for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
   {
       cout<<"p["<<i<<"]:"<<p[i]<<endl;
   }
   delete[] p;
   return 0; 
}
```

Output in compile online:
Compiling the source code....
$g++ main.cpp -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmpxx -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1

Executing the program....
$demo
p[0]:0 p[1]:1 p[2]:2 p[3]:3 p[4]:4 p[5]:5 p[6]:6 p[7]:7 p[8]:8 p[9]:9 p[10]:10 p[11]:11 p[12]:12 p[13]:13 p[14]:14 p[15]:15 p[16]:16 p[17]:17 p[18]:18 p[19]:19 * glibc detected * demo: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001b69010 * ======= Backtrace: ========= /lib64/libc.so.6[0x3170875e76] /lib64/libc.so.6[0x31708789b3] demo[0x400bff] /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x317081ed5d] demo[0x4009e9] ======= Memory map: ======== 00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 07:00 2195935 /web/com/141607803728670/demo 00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 07:00 2195935 /web/com/141607803728670/demo 01b69000-01b8a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 [heap] 3170000000-3170020000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 8257538 /lib64/ld-2.12.so 317021f000-3170220000 r--p 0001f000 fd:00 8257538 /lib64/ld-2.12.so 3170220000-3170221000 rw-p 00020000 fd:00 8257538 /lib64/ld-2.12.so 3170221000-3170222000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 3170400000-3170456000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 14027864 /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.3.5.0 3170456000-3170656000 ---p 00056000 fd:00 14027864 /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.3.5.0 3170656000-317065b000 rw-p 00056000 fd:00 14027864 /usr/lib64/libgmp.so.3.5.0 3170800000-317098a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 8257542 /lib64/libc-2.12.so 317098a000-3170b8a000 ---p 0018a000 fd:00 8257542 /lib64/libc-2.12.so 3170b8a000-3170b8e000 r--p 0018a000 fd:00 8257542 /lib64/libc-2.12.so 3170b8e000-3170b8f000 rw-p 0018e000 fd:00 8257542 /lib64/libc-2.12.so 3170b8f000-3170b94000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

Comment: What happens if you change the test for the first `for` loop to just `i<20`?

Comment: Yeah! Thank you! That works! after executing '(p+i)<(p+20*sizeof(int))', p points to the garblic address( Address of array int[19] + 4 bytes). Thank you very much.

Comment: Remember to tag language when you show code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Scott Hunter, the following snippet works now.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int *p;
   p = new int[20];
   //for(int i=0;(p+i)<(p+20*sizeof(int));i++)
   for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
   {
       p[i]=i;
   }

   for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
   {
       cout<<"p["<<i<<"]:"<<p[i]<<endl;
   }
   delete[] p;
   return 0; 
}
```